# Azure iOS SDK error when publishing

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've created a small app using Azure iOS SDK. When trying to archive the app I get the following error

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Mayu/Documents/development/git/pizzatogo/iPhoneApp/Pizza to Go/WindowsAzureMessaging.framework/WindowsAzureMessaging, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/Mayu/Documents/development/git/pizzatogo/iPhoneApp/Pizza to Go/WindowsAzureMessaging.framework/WindowsAzureMessaging (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Mayu/Documents/development/git/pizzatogo/iPhoneApp/Pizza to Go/WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework/WindowsAzureMobileServices, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/Mayu/Documents/development/git/pizzatogo/iPhoneApp/Pizza to Go/WindowsAzureMobileServices.framework/WindowsAzureMobileServices (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSUser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AuthService.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MSClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AuthService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea what went wrong and where... seems some reference error.

DId some google search and changed the architecture of the app to armv7 and still no luck. Can someone help me out here as I'm very new to Objective C and iOS stuff. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Which version of the azure mobile services iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using the version 1.1.0

Comment: Is there a 64bit version?

Comment: @jeffamaphone I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Seems not.  I'm doing some saber-rattling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was mine. I had 64 also in the build architecture. Removed it and set it to only armv7 and it worked like charm.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is your problem.  What if you want to have a 64bit app?  SDK 1.1.1 still has this issue.

Comment: Ah, you can build it yourself: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services